# How can i know whether my app crush facebook policy

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, policy

How can i know whether my app crush facebook policy? i create a custom facebook post preview for facebook api post ..Is it will crush with facebook policy?

Comment: What do you mean by crush? Are you asking if what you're developing goes against the policy? If so, you should take the time to just Google it. I will post the link this time as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

https://developers.facebook.com/policy/